# Google map engine is not being shown in Kindle webview

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, kindle-fire

I am opening a Google map engine URL in a webview, and it opens homepage correctly, but when I click on "open map", or "create new map", it doesn't show anything except the top menu bar. It works fine in the kindle browser, but not in a webview.
[image]

After clicking on buttons "create new map" it shows me this the picture below.
Clicking on "open map" it shows me options to select a map but am unable to select these options. If by chance am able to select option than it again shows me this blank picture. 
[image]

I am using a Webview client with the Kindle User Agent and webview client. Its settings are:

```
wvMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMain);

        wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvMain.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        wvMain.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wvMain.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wvMain.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wvMain.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wvMain.setWebViewClient(wvClient);

        String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; Kindle Fire Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/533.1";
        wvMain.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
```

can anybody tell me that what's wrong with it.Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you provided the internet as well as access network permission ?

Comment: of course,that's why the home page is being displayed :)

Comment: Is there anything useful in the logs?

Comment: no,it runs fine in other android devices. Only behaving different in kindle devices :(

Answer (score 1):

Kindle Fire doesn't include Google services, so Amazon supplies its own mapping API (https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/maps).

Comment: That's right. You cant use Google maps on kindle, instead you need to use their own API, which isn't that different.